# Is there an alternative to gulp-svg-sprite for .NET?

Tags: node.js, .net, svg, gulp

I am building a .NET MVC website and I am attempting to build a frontend without the use of Node/React etc. I have installed various packages for bundling/minification of CSS/JS and now need one for SVGs.

On other sites, we have used [gulp-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite) to essentially bundle up all of the SVGs in the project into one file. I can't find an alternative for this in .NET - is there one?